# App doesn't appear while searching on Google play

Tags: android

I just published my first app in Google play. It doesn't appear while I'm searching by its name but it does when I search by package name in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Google play need some time to show your app to the store.

For my experience,, about 2-3 hour.
But something will go to one day.
I think they need to sync. to the server over the world.